# Network Monitoring program to use in Windows 7

Tags: windows, networking

I have a Windows 7 machine.

I want to capture and **save the logs**, of all TCP/IP packets that pass through my network adapter.
And i would like to use, if possible, a 'fully portable' application, also if it's a paid licensed.

**TcpWiew** seems to me good, but it don't have the possibility to save the log of entries (it can save a log only clicking 'save', but seems to me that there is not the 'automated logs save function').

I saw there is a portable edition of **Wireshark**.
I've downloaded, but to use it, it need the installation of **NpCap**, and i don't like so much the idea of install that software.
So i was unable to check if Wireshark can automatically save the logs.

I saw also **Nirsoft SmartSniff**.
Reading the description of this software, it provides 3 methods for capturing TCP/IP packets:

1. Raw Sockets - But this method have some limitations and problems.
2. WinPcap Capture Driver - But i should install WinPcap (and it's the same as NpCap for Wireshark), and it seems to me don't work in Windows 7.
3. Microsoft Network Monitor Driver 3 - This method use the **Microsoft Network Monitor Driver 3.x** and should be already installed in the o.s., or can be downloaded from Microsoft directly.

So i think i understood that, to work correctly, a Network Monitor, should use libraries (NpCap, WinPcap, Microsoft Network Monitor Driver 3.x ...).

And if i have to install some libraries, i would prefer the Microsoft ones.

So i'm searching for a Network Monitoring program, that:

- can record all TCP/IP activities (it doesn't matter the content, but it's necessary the protocol used, the port and the remote address).
- is portable.
- it don't uses libraries, or it uses Microsoft libraries.
- can automatically save logs (so later, i can check all records).
- It doesn't matter if it's free or paid licensed.

Any suggestion? or tips, if i have mistake something in my considerations?

P.S. Does someone know about **System Informer**? it seems good, ...But not sure if can automatically save logs, ...And seems to me not portable...

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer [by Scott Chamberlainn](https://superuser.com/questions/543718/how-do-i-log-outgoing-tcp-connections-from-my-computer)

> I would recommend using [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). It is made by the same people who made TCPView but it shows a lot more. It also allows you to log the information to disk so you can look at it later.
>
> Note: The program will need to be open and running for it to record the logs, but if you set it up to save the logs to disk as it records them you can always review them later.

It sounds like what you are looking for.  I havent used it for saving myself.

Comment: Thank you so much! Was exactly what i was looking for. ...But, why  did you said 'I havent used it for saving myself'? Do you fear about that program? ...it seems to me that Sysinterinals programs are quite good safe, also verified and published by Microsoft website.

Comment: After download and tried, i can't choose your answer: There are no more downladable Process Monitor versions for Windows 7: the last working version it's 3.86, but no more safe download link are provided from Sysinterinals/Microsoft. Neither at Wayback Machine. It is possible to find some link over internet but are not safe: all size are different... So i found an old version i downloaded some years ago and i tested: there is no possibility to track/record TCP/IP log, like remote ip and port used, so, sorry, not useful to me.